# Profiling Node.JS (code) execution time in Linux

Tags: javascript, eclipse, node.js, profiling, dtrace

I am looking for a method to do precise `Node.JS` **profiling** of script execution times on Linux.

There are interesting projects like the [NodeTime.com Performance Profiler](http://nodetime.com/), but this profiles the timing of I/O httprequests and such, not **execution time of lines of code**.

I am looking for a way to figure out exactly where I can optimize my Javascript, **where most of the time is spent**, etc.

---

One interesting method I've seen is trying to [create a FlameGraph using DTrace](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/12/16/flame-graphs/) to profile Node.JS.

However, `dtrace` is very Solaris-specific.

- For Linux (Debian/Ubuntu), `dtrace` can be found in the `sytemtap-sdt-dev` package. However, `stap dtrace` is not the same, and lacks all relevant hooks/probes.
- Paul Fox made a port from the Unix version. It's more feature complete but somehow the hooks/probes don't work in userspace as the Solaris one, and also cannot be used to profile node.
  ftp://crisp.dyndns-server.com/pub/release/website/dtrace/ (It's pretty easy to build, see README.)
- There's also an `Oracle` port, but noone [would recommend](http://dtrace.org/blogs/ahl/2011/10/10/oel-this-is-not-dtrace/) it. Apparently, it only has about 0,1 percent of the probes the Paul Fox port. (Which is ironic, because `Oracle` was formerly `Sun`, original authors of `dtrace` for `Solaris`)

---

**How, in Linux, using the terminal or using Eclipse, can I profile the code of my Node.JS scripts?** I'm looking for something specific like the Zend Profiler shows execution times of each command in code of PHP scripts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're not against using [nodetime](http://nodetime.com/), it actually does have CPU profiling:

See: **http://nodetime.com/blog/cpu-profiling-with-nodetime**

[image]

Comment: Nice, I missed that before. I prefer a flame graph style profiler, but I will try this until someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 8):

"look" is a very good tool made by Vadim for profiling NodeJS app.

Take a look here:

https://github.com/baryshev/look

Comment: It appears "[look](https://github.com/baryshev/look)" is a _fork_ of [nodetime](http://nodetime.com/) negating the need to have it communicate profiling information to a 3rd party website. I haven't tried it yet, but this is potentially pretty cool.

Comment: I tried this but couldn't understand how to use it. It shows me "0.02% - channel.onread" (don't know what it is) and "99.98% - (program)", with no way to go into the "program" and see the time of specific routines.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.org/package/node.profiler
Exactly what you need...
It runs your project in monitor mode and it generates a chart after you are done with details on functions, each how many times it was called and the time it spent there.